# Jigsaw Puzzle Solver

Tags: java, algorithm, stack-overflow, puzzle

Ok, so I have a 3 x 3 jig saw puzzle game that I am writing and I am stuck on the solution method.

```
public Piece[][] solve(int r, int c) {
    if (isSolved())
        return board;
    board[r][c] = null;
    for (Piece p : pieces) {
        if (p.equals(prev[r][c])) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            break;
        }
        if (tryInsert(p, r, c)) {
            pieces.remove(p);
            System.out.println("why");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (getPieceAt(r, c) != null)
        return solve(nextLoc(r, c).x, nextLoc(r, c).y);
    else {
        if (prev[prevLoc(r, c).x][prevLoc(r, c).y] == null)
            prev[prevLoc(r, c).x][prevLoc(r, c).y] = getPieceAt(
                    prevLoc(r, c).x, prevLoc(r, c).y);
        prev[r][c] = null;
        pieces.add(getPieceAt(prevLoc(r, c).x, prevLoc(r, c).y));
        return solve(prevLoc(r, c).x, prevLoc(r, c).y);
    }
}
```

I know I haven't provided much info on the puzzle, but my algorithm should work regardless of the specifics. I've tested all helper methods, `pieces` is a `List` of all the unused `Piece`s, `tryInsert` attempts to insert the piece in all possible orientations, and if the piece can be inserted, it will be. The idea of `prev` is to prevent the program from going thru the same combinations of pieces over and over.

Unfortunately, when I test it, I get a `StackOverflowError`. What's wrong?